# How to change the command of the application launcher in Docky?

Tags: launcher, docky

I've dragged the application launcher from main menu to the docky panel. Now, I want to change the command that starts the application (I need to add some arguments). I can change it the main menu using editor.

How to change it in the Docky launcher? Does Docky store the launcher files somewhere so they can be edited?

I am using Docky 2.2.0 (bzr docky r1807 ppa) on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Robert Dyer](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=urqqCBEAAABYXOzp3gd13AlTYYInIkkykdEasx1kiYTQavV7mdW13Q) ([here](http://groups.google.com/group/docky-dock/browse_thread/thread/5923cb11981ba688?pli=1)), you should change the launcher at the main menu and then drag it to Docky because the launcher at Docky [can't be configured directly](http://groups.google.com/group/docky-dock/browse_thread/thread/5923cb11981ba688?pli=1).

Answer (score 0):

Added bug report few mins ago ...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra/+bug/665656

Edit: sorry, bad topic